# How do I ignore a delimiter within quoted strings in R using fread

Tags: r

I have a text file which is delimited by "|" to separate columns. But sometimes some invoice numbers also have the pipe delimiter within them but within quoted strings but using the below code separates the pipe in between the invoice numbers which is not what I want, how do I get Fread to ignore delimiters that are in between 2 quotes ?

```
Notepad File = "DETAIL|29117|Lake Louise Payment Request Policy|Centex Petroleum(CEP001)-39105||39105|2022-11-27|2022-12-17|57562.5100|57562.5100|2022-12-06|2022-12-10|||||CDEWITT||||||||||||||||||LLSA|||||||||||LLSA|LLSA|Y|0.0000|0.0000|B5AC4BCA16504EAA8391|2022-12-01|CLIENT|||||0.0000|Sage 300|Sage 300|9999|3704.5100|3889.7400|DR|CAD|124|Canada, Dollar|9999|LLSA|01|1000|6085|CDEWITT||||||||||||||||191472|||||101351|accounts.payable@skilouise.com|John||Staffieri|accounts.payable@skilouise.com|||||||||||||||||||||||||||LLSA/LLI|LLSA||||7|6|FED FUEL CHARGE|2249   |DEFAULT|27625.0000|0.1341|3704.5100|LLSA|01|1000|6085||||||||||||||||||||||Centex Petroleum|CEP001|CEP001|7EC7866E97F74B85B04D|203, 1717 - 10th Street NW|||CALGARY|AB|T2M 4S2|CA|||0||||||||||||||||N|||||||||||||||||||185.2300||0.0000||0.0000||0.0000|||||0.0000|0.0000||||||N|||||||||||||||||0.0000|2741.0800|0.0000|||54821.4300|0.0000||3704.5100|
DETAIL|29117|Lake Louise Payment Request Policy|Centex Petroleum(CEP001)-39105||39105|2022-11-27|2022-12-17|57562.5100|57562.5100|2022-12-06|2022-12-10|||||CDEWITT||||||||||||||||||LLSA|||||||||||LLSA|LLSA|Y|0.0000|0.0000|B5AC4BCA16504EAA8391|2022-12-01|CLIENT|||||0.0000|Sage 300|Sage 300|9999|454.1000|476.8100|DR|CAD|124|Canada, Dollar|9999|LLSA|01|1000|6085|CDEWITT||||||||||||||||191473|||||101351|accounts.payable@skilouise.com|John||Staffieri|accounts.payable@skilouise.com|||||||||||||||||||||||||||LLSA/LLI|LLSA||||7|7|ExtenData(EXD001)-5642530-IN|2249   |DEFAULT|10091.0000|0.0450|454.1000|LLSA|01|1000|6085||||||||||||||||||||||Centex Petroleum|CEP001|CEP001|7EC7866E97F74B85B04D|203, 1717 - 10th Street NW|||CALGARY|AB|T2M 4S2|CA|||0||||||||||||||||N|||||||||||||||||||22.7100||0.0000||0.0000||0.0000|||||0.0000|0.0000||||||N|||||||||||||||||0.0000|2741.0800|0.0000|||54821.4300|0.0000||454.1000|
DETAIL|28329|Lake Louise Payment Request Policy|Coinamatic(COI001)-SALES000000546031||SALES000000546031|2022-12-01|2022-12-01|916.5200|916.5200|2022-11-14|2022-12-11|||||NBAGGLEY||||||||||||||||||LLSA|||||||||||LLSA|LLSA|Y|0.0000|0.0000|E7B64B5B064F4987A2EF|2022-11-11|CLIENT|||||0.0000|Sage 300|Sage 300|9999|872.8800|916.5200|DR|CAD|124|Canada, Dollar|9999|LLSA|01|9500|6350|NBAGGLEY||||||||||||||||191875|||||101351|accounts.payable@skilouise.com|John||Staffieri|accounts.payable@skilouise.com|||||||||||||||||||||||||||LLSA/LLI|LLSA||||1|1|Rental Fee|2249   |DEFAULT|1.0000|872.8800|872.8800|LLSA|01|9500|6350||||||||||||||||||||||Coinamatic|COI001|COI001|1E980633B41949BAAADA|301 Matheson Blvd West|||MISSISSAUGA|ON|L5R 3G3|CA|||(250) 344-2381||||||||||||||||N|101045318RT0001||||||||||||||||||43.6400||0.0000||0.0000||0.0000|||||0.0000|0.0000||||||N|||||||||||||||||0.0000|43.6400|0.0000|||872.8800|0.0000||872.8800|
DETAIL|28141|Lake Louise Payment Request Policy|"Endeavor Design Inc.(EDI001)-INVC7-6191 | LLOU760-1"||"INVC7-6191 | LLOU760-1"|2022-10-14|2022-11-13|56608.8900|56608.8900|2022-11-09|2022-11-12|||||AE23006||||||||||||||||||LLSA|||||||||||LLSA|LLSA|Y|0.0000|0.0000|155192A2BA72496B8D87|2022-11-05|CLIENT|||||0.0000|Sage 300|Sage 300|9999|50962.4900|53510.6200|DR|CAD|124|Canada, Dollar|9999|LLSA|01|3100|1350|AE23006||||||||||||||||181764|||||168|Christiane.Morel@skilouise.com|Christiane||Morel|Christiane.Morel@skilouise.com|||||||||||||||||||||||||||LLSA/LLI|LLSA||||2|1|Subtotal|2249   |DEFAULT|1.0000|50962.4900|50962.4900|LLSA|01|3100|1350||||||||||||||||||||||Endeavor Design Inc.|EDI001|EDI001|EB6AA8003B374774AF7E|1737 West 3rd Avenue, Unit 110|||VANCOUVER|BC|V6J 1K7|CA|||0||||||||||||||||N|||||||||||||||||||2548.1300||0.0000||0.0000||0.0000|||||0.0000|0.0000||||||N|||||||||||||||||0.0000|2695.6700|0.0000|||53913.2200|0.0000||50962.4900|
DETAIL|28141|Lake Louise Payment Request Policy|"Endeavor Design Inc.(EDI001)-INVC7-6191 | LLOU760-1"||"INVC7-6191 | LLOU760-1"|2022-10-14|2022-11-13|56608.8900|56608.8900|2022-11-09|2022-11-12|||||AE23006||||||||||||||||||LLSA|||||||||||LLSA|LLSA|Y|0.0000|0.0000|155192A2BA72496B8D87|2022-11-05|CLIENT|||||0.0000|Sage 300|Sage 300|9999|2950.7300|3098.2700|DR|CAD|124|Canada, Dollar|9999|LLSA|01|3100|6515|AE23006||||||||||||||||181765|||||168|Christiane.Morel@skilouise.com|Christiane||Morel|Christiane.Morel@skilouise.com|||||||||||||||||||||||||||LLSA/LLI|LLSA||||2|2|Freight|2249   |DEFAULT|1.0000|2950.7300|2950.7300|LLSA|01|3100|6515||||||||||||||||||||||Endeavor Design Inc.|EDI001|EDI001|EB6AA8003B374774AF7E|1737 West 3rd Avenue, Unit 110|||VANCOUVER|BC|V6J 1K7|CA|||0||||||||||||||||N|||||||||||||||||||147.5400||0.0000||0.0000||0.0000|||||0.0000|0.0000||||||N|||||||||||||||||0.0000|2695.6700|0.0000|||53913.2200|0.0000||2950.7300|")
```

**Code:

```
Invoice <- fread("invoice.txt", sep="|", quote="\"", headers=FALSE, fill=TRUE, col_types=c(V6="character"))
```

This works well in all cases except when there happens to be a delimiter in between a quoted string.

The Endeavor Design invoice number has a pipe delimiter within the quotes - the original invoice number is `"INVC7-6191 | LLOU760-1"` and this should be retained as is.

Answer (score 0):

There is no `headers=` or `colClasses` argumemts in `data.table::fread`, maybe you were used to an old version, not sure.

```
r <- data.table::fread('invoice.txt',  sep="|", quote="\"", header=FALSE, fill=TRUE, 
                       colClasses=c(V6="character"))

r[, 'V6'] |> unlist() |> grep(pat='INV', value=TRUE)
#                      V64                      V65 
# "INVC7-6191 | LLOU760-1" "INVC7-6191 | LLOU760-1"
```

Comment: Hi Jay, thanks for your help, is there a way that I can use the fread to do the same thing you mentioned without the grep as next time I might have an invoice with a completely different pattern ? Maybe I could just replace the delimiter within quotes ?